# How to deal with Duplicated variables in EntityFrameWork Core

Tags: many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I need help figuring out how to prevent duplicates of a variable. I am building a blog, and don't want the same tags to be created over and over each time I use it.

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasKey(t => new { t.PostId, t.TagId });

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Post)
            .WithMany(p => p.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.PostId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<PostTag>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.PostTags)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TagId);
    }
}

public class Post
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public string TagId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<PostTag> PostTags { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Do I need to create a custom method to make this happen, or is there a way to get it done using Fluent APi?
If the tag already exists, I want to instead add the post to the already existing list of posts with that same tagName.

Comment: Do you mean row duplicate?

Comment: No, I can deal with that. I just mean, on the database